# Attaching Documentation in Visual Studio (à la Eclipse)

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to Visual Studio (2012) and having come from using Eclipse, I'm finding myself missing the ability to hover my mouse over a method and receive a dialogue detailing the parameters and any accompanying comments.

In this particular example, I'm using the OpenGL SDK with C++ in Visual Studio, and I would like to be able to quickly get at the documentation without having to jump between VS and http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/.

Is there a way that I can attach the documentation somehow so that I can view it from within Visual Studio itself without needing to manually search?

Answer (score 0):

visual studio does provide the functionality you are looking for as a tooltip (instead of a dialogue) when you hover long enough (2-3 seconds). For this to work correctly and more usefully though, you'd need the functions to be documented properly in the code itself. 
Check the following questions for more information on how intellisense tooltip works :
[How to get full intellisense tooltip comments working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413854/how-to-get-full-intellisense-tooltip-comments-working)

[Documenting C++/CLI library code for use from c# - best tools and practices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040479/documenting-c-cli-library-code-for-use-from-c-sharp-best-tools-and-practices)

By default though, intellisense will simply display the comment above the function declaration or deninition (which ever comment is larger, it seems). It takes a while longer when you hover first time over a function, so be patient and retry :)

Answer (score 0):

you can type in the code 3 slash /// and visual studio automaticalli write a xml template for the documentation of the method/class/property.

next you can go in the project properties. Build tab, Output section, XML documentation file, and enter the filename. It will be built on every build of the project.

You could try NDOC or SandCastle if you dont mind using 3rd party tools.